# Вывод подкатегорий

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, такая проблема :
Хочу вывести меню с категориями и подкатегориями, смотрел похожие вопросы но что то не понял, **подскажите что я делаю не так ?**
Имею две таблицы :
Род.таблица `category` и Доч.категория `statti`, хочу вывести все записи из `category` и её дочерние категории в таблице `statti`.
На данный момент у меня выводится все записи из Род.таблицы `category` но только  с одной записью от дочерней таблицы  `statti`.
**Что я делаю не так** 
***Функция:***

```
   public function get_left_bar(){
   $query = "SELECT
   c.name_category, c.cat, s.title, count(s.cat)as cat_count
   FROM category c,
   statti s  
   WHERE c.cat = s.cat
   GROUP BY c.cat";

   $row = array();
   $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$query);
    if(!$result) {
    exit(mysqli_error());
    }
    for($i = 0;$i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++) {
        $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
    return $row;}
```

***Вывожу:***

```
<?php $i = 1;?>
<?php foreach($left_bar as $row) :?>

<li class="nav-item-link dropdown ">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase text-expanded font-weight-bold d-lg" href="#" 
id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
<?php echo $row['name_category']?>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu font-weight-bold d-lg">
<a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold d-lg" href='?option=menu&id_menu=<?php echo $row['id_menu']? 
>'><?php echo $row['title'];?>
</a>
<?php if($i != count($left_bar)) :?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php $i++;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</li>
```

**var_dump**

```
 object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) {
 ["current_field"]=> int(0) 
 ["field_count"]=> int(4) 
 ["lengths"]=> NULL 
 ["num_rows"]=> int(3) 
 ["type"]=> int(0) 
 }
 array(3) {
 [0]=> array(4) {
 ["name_category"]=> 
 string(34) "Андроид" 
 ["cat"]=> string(1) "1" 
 ["title"]=> string(53) "Приложение. " 
 ["cat_count"]=> string(1) "1" 
 } 
 [1]=> array(4) {
 ["name_category"]=> string(34) "Шаблоны" 
 ["cat"]=> string(1) "2" 
 ["title"]=> string(64) "Шаблон 2" 
 ["cat_count"]=> string(1) "3" 
 } 
 [2]=> array(4) {
 ["name_category"]=> string(38) "Системы " 
 ["cat"]=> string(1) "3" 
 ["title"]=> string(50) "Система 2" 
 ["cat_count"]=> string(1) "6" 
 } 
 }
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN вам в помощь

Comment: У вас есть цикл для вывода всех `category`, но я не заметил цикла для вывода `statti`. По этому и выводится только одна запись.

Comment: @Pashok- Я также думаю что проблема в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

Немного поправил и причесал Ваш код, особенно вторую часть. Попробуйте его, если не работает, то раскомментируйте указанные строки - посмотрите, что в переменных.

UPD: изменил запрос.
UPD2: изменил запрос.

```
public function get_left_bar()
{
    $query = "SELECT c.name_category, c.cat, s.title, count(s.cat) as cat_count
        FROM statti s
        LEFT JOIN category c
        ON c.cat = s.cat
        ORDER BY c.cat";

    $result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }

    // var_dump($result); // строка один
    $row = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows_result = mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++) {
        $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
    // var_dump($row); // строка два
    return $row;
}
```

в представление:

```
<?php foreach ($left_bar as $row) { ?>

    <li class="nav-item-link dropdown ">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase text-expanded font-weight-bold d-lg" href="#"
           id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <?php echo $row['name_category']; ?>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu font-weight-bold d-lg">
            <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold d-lg" href='?option=menu&id_menu=<?php echo $row['id_menu']; ?>'>
                <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
            </a>

        </div>
    </li>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ . Но это не сработало. Также выводит только один каталог в категории .

Comment: Я добавил данные `var_dump` к вопросу.

Comment: ок, давайте пошагово пытаться. поправил запрос с учетом @DaemonHK. Дайте вывод,  пожалуйста.

Comment: я и сам пробовал через `LEFT JOIN` но и это для меня не сработало , думаю надо цикл перебора править присвоить ключи. Но пака опыта не хватает на такой подход , буду думать. Спасибо за помощь.   Если будет интересно посмотреть как это работает  на примере , смотрите в меню  , вот ссылка:    https://info.shihzamanapp.com/

Comment: не бывает, чтобы именно для Вас не работало) Сейчас запрос должен вернуть все записи из таблицы 'statti' плюс дополнительные поля c сортировкой по родительской категории. еще раз обновил запрос.
Дайте вывод измененного запроса.

Comment: Я обновил свой скрипт на сайте , пройдите посылке выше и посмотрите  сами  как выводится... и гляньте в на блок с права , категории с числом вложений , они просто все вместе собрались.

Comment: Думаю как _@Pashok_ проблема в цикле , нету цикла для statti.

Comment: а зачем вы смешиваете ООП  с процедурным стилем? Про понятие родительская таблиц никогда раньше не слышал. Названия полей таблиц тоже лучше поменять(cat, name_category не воспринимается)

Comment: @МаксМаксимус- У меня есть методы которые требовали смешивания  ООП с процедурным стилем.

Comment: какого цикла? В $left_bar у Вас должно быть столько элементов, сколько записей в таблице statti. Вывод я смотрел, он не изменился. Дело, конечно, Ваше: не хотите решать проблему - не решайте.

Comment: "У меня есть методы которые требовали смешивания ООП с процедурным стилем" - это как понять?

Comment: @МаксМаксимус - чтобы иметь такие запросы в строке поиска `domain.com/?option=view&id_text=105`

Comment: @Shihzamanapp разве возможность передачи GET-запроса зависит от парадигмы программирования?

Comment: @Yakoffka - Мне не мешает использовать несколько парадигм программирования. Так как мой уровень на данный момент начинающий.